# Django website not checking the links correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mysql, django

I have a django website that contains a table with many servers details.
In one of the columns in the table there is "ILO" IP of a server.

I wanted the website to check if the "ILO" IP works in http request, and if it does, then it should show the link and if not, shows a text instead.

Therefore, in the result, will be servers that has http link to ILO IP and some without.

Under my main class in the views I created a function called "checkUrlAvailable" which I try to use in my index.html and check with if condition if I get true or false..

for some reason I get the errorr-

Could not parse the remainder: '(server.IP)' from 'checkUrlAvailable(server.IP)'

Does anyone know why?

index.html-

```
  <tr>
        <th><center> #</center></th>
        <th width="100%"><center>  Server Name </center></th>
        <th><center>  Owner </center></th>
        <th><center>  Project </center></th>
        <th width="100%"><center>  Description </center></th>
        <th width="100%"><center>  IP Address </center></th>
        <th width="100%"><center> ILO </center></th>
        <th><center>  Rack </center></th>
        <th><center>  Status </center></th>
        <th><center>  Actions {{ response }}  </center></th>


        </tr>
        </thead>
    <tbody>

                {% for server in posts %}


        <tr>
          <div class ="server">
            <td></td>
            <td style='white-space: nowrap'><center>{{ server.ServerName }}</center></td>
            <td width="100%"><center>{{ server.Owner }}</center></td>
            <td style='white-space: nowrap'><center>{{ server.Project }}</center></td>
            <td style='white-space: nowrap'><center>{{ server.Description }}</center></td>
            <td width="100%"><center>{{ server.IP }}</center></td>
            <td style='white-space: nowrap'><center>
                {% if checkUrlAvailable(server.ILO) is True %}
      <a href="//{{ server.ServerName }}.ilo.lab.radcom.co.il"> http://{{ server.ServerName }}.ilo.lab.radcom.co.il </a>
            {% else %}
        http://{{ server.ServerName }}.ilo.lab.radcom.co.il
            {% endif %}

            <td width="100%"><center>{{ server.Rack }}</center></td>
            <td width="100%"><h4><span class="badge badge-success">Online</span></h4></td></center>
```

views.py -

```
class HomeView(TemplateView):

    template_name = 'serverlist.html'

    def checkUrlAvailable(url):
        resp = requests.head(url)
        if resp.status_code == 200:
            return True
        else:
            return False


    def get(self, request):

        form = HomeForm()
        query = request.GET.get("q")
        posts = serverlist.objects.all()



        forms = {}

        if query:
            posts = serverlist.objects.filter(Q(ServerName__icontains=query) | Q(Owner__icontains=query) | Q(Project__icontains=query) | Q(Description__icontains=query) | Q(IP__icontains=query) | Q(ILO__icontains=query) | Q(Rack__icontains=query))
        else:
            posts = serverlist.objects.all()
        for post in posts:
            forms[post.id] = HomeForm(instance=post)
        args = {'form' : form,'forms': forms, 'posts' : posts}




        return render(request, self.template_name,args)

    def post(self,request):
        form = HomeForm(request.POST)
        posts = serverlist.objects.all()
        forms = {}


        if form.is_valid(): # Checks if validation of the forms passed
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.save()
            messages.success(request,'{0} has been added successfully!'.format(post.ServerName))

            return redirect('serverlist')
        messages.error(request,'Servername is required, please refresh the page and try again.')
        for post in posts:
            forms[post.id] = HomeForm(instance=post)
        args = {'form' : form, 'forms': forms, 'posts' : posts}

        return render(request, self.template_name,args)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot call function inside django template. You need to define custom [template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-template-tags/) or you can move `checkUrlAvailable` inside `serverlist` model:

```
class serverlist(models.Model):
   ...
    def checkUrlAvailable(self):
        resp = requests.head(self.ILO)
        if resp.status_code == 200:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

and use it in template like this:

```
{% if server.checkUrlAvailable %}
```

Comment: {% if server.checkUrlAvailable('www.google.com') is True %} ?

Comment: @EilonAshkenazi no, just `{% if server.checkUrlAvailable is True %}` it will check current server ILO value. If you need to pass any other value to this function you need to implement template tag.

Comment: Ok, now the website is working. 
But, all the ILO links not working even though some of them I know for sure supposed to work. IT seem like the function returns False for every thing..
Is status code 200 is right? or should I change a function?

Comment: @EilonAshkenazi try just check if ILO is filled or not: `if self. ILO` without using requests.

Comment: Ok I tried to debug and I think the problem is that the ILO is just a string of: 172.16.10.10
And maybe I need to add the http:// before...
So I tried resp = requests.head("http://" + self.ILO)
Still not working... but am I right with the idea?

Comment: @EilonAshkenazi yes, i suppose it's true. Also you can try to use `get` instead of `head`: `resp = requests.get("http://" + self.ILO)`

Comment: Its still getting False... 
if resp.status_code == 200: Are we sure that this condition is ok with ILO web? Maybe I should do another condition?
How can I print the resp.status_code? It will help me debug and see if I get different numbers

Comment: @EilonAshkenazi can you `print(resp.status_code)` for diffent ILO?

Comment: Oh and I also did : resp = requests.head("www.google.co.il") and it still false... so the problem is not with my IPS or addresses its with the function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162412/discussion-between-eilon-ashkenazi-and-neverwalkaloner).